# Using GStreamer to serve RTP stream over RTSP

Tags: linux, gstreamer, rtsp, rtp

I have a RTP stream coming in from a HW encoder that I would like to serve out to RTSP clients using Gstreamer 0.10. Using the "test-video.c" as a starting point I was able to serve the videotestsrc, but have not had any luck serving an incoming RTP Stream. I modified the pipeline as follows.

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, "(gstrtpbin name=rtpbin latency=200 udpsrc caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=MP2T-ES, payload=33\" port=5000 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin. ! queue name=pay0 "
```

But it does not work. I'm guessing it has to do with the caps not carrying through properly.

When attempting playback I get the following messages on the server

```
0:00:02.582382334  4325    0x12458 WARN                bin gstbin.c:2399:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<media-pipeline> failed to query latency
0:00:02.786215669  4325 0x2bf03a40 WARN                basesink gstbasesink.c:3638:gst_base_sink_chain_unlocked:<multiudpsink0> warning: Internal data flow problem.
0:00:02.786330002  4325 0x2bf03a40 WARN                basesink gstbasesink.c:3638:gst_base_sink_chain_unlocked:<multiudpsink0> warning: Received buffer without a new-segment. Assuming timestamps start from 0.
0:00:02.786540668  4325   0x13cde0 WARN                rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:1511:default_handle_message: 0x1200b0: got warning Internal data flow problem. (gstbasesink.c(3638): gst_base_sink_chain_unlocked (): /GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstMultiUDPSink:multiudpsink0: Received buffer without a new-segment. Assuming timestamps start from 0.)
0:00:02.787497335  4325   0x189238 WARN                     bin gstbin.c:2395:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<media-pipeline> did not really configure latency of 0:00:00.200000000
0:00:02.816800002  4325    0x12458 WARN              rtspclient rtsp-client.c:782:handle_play_request: RTP-Info cannot be determined for stream 0
0:00:02.818120668  4325    0x12458 WARN                     bin gstbin.c:2395:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<media-pipeline> did not really configure latency of 0:00:00.200000000
```

The "internal dataflow problem" is not a promising sign. The incoming stream is H.264 video inside a MPEG2 Transport stream. Any ideas on how to solve this problem ?

Thanks,

/Otto

Answer (score 0):

You might need a mpegtsdemux element (in gstreamer bad plugins) to demux the video stream from the MPEG2TS.